# assistance with getting part of value with powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I need assistance with a powershell script.

I have a value - 2.0.0.0 (it could be any value seperated with the 3 full stops)

I want to just get the first three numbers eg 2.0.0

With powershell, how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A regular expression is a flexible way to do this:

```
"1.2.3.4" -replace "(.*)\.(.*)\.(.*)\.(.*)",'$1.$2.$3'
```

or inspired by Shay Levy's answer:

You could use the toString method with a fieldcount of three:

```
([version]"1.2.3.4").tostring(3)
```

Comment: Oooh...and the "now you have two problems" solution wins out. :)

Answer (score 4):

Here's another way:

```
 PS> '2.0.0.0'.split('.')[0..2] -join '.'
 2.0.0
```

By the way, you can cast it to a system.version object and work with it's properties:

```
PS> [version]'2.0.0.0'

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  -------- 
2      0      0      0
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
$a =  "2.0.0.0"

$a.Remove( $a.LastIndexOf('.') )

2.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing at all wrong with the other answers, but just to show more diversity:

```
[string]::Join('.', '2.0.0.0'.Split('.')[0..2])
```